# calling invokeAndWait from the EDT

Tags: java, swing, events, awt

I have a problem following from my [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435251/error-when-creating-jframe-from-jframe/). I also have the code `SwingUtillities.invokeAndWait` somewhere else in the code base, but when I remove this the gui does not refresh. If I dont remove it the error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread
 at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
 at game.player.humanplayer.model.HumanPlayer.act(HumanPlayer.java:69)
```

The code in HumanPlayer.act is:

```
public Action act(final Action[] availiableActions) {
  try {

   SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     gui.update(availiableActions);
    }
   });
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  synchronized(performedAction){
   while(!hasPerformedAction()){
    try {
     performedAction.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   setPerformedAction(false); 
  }

  return getActionPerfomed();
 }
```

Image of threads when in debug as screen doesn't paint:
[alt text http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/6669/69288941.png](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/6669/69288941.png)

Text version of stack:

```
ui.startup.LoginScreen at localhost:51050
 -> Deamon Thread [AWT-Windows] (Running)
 -> Thread [AWT-Shutdown] (Running)
 -> Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Running)
 -> Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)
```

Comment: Do you have a `repaint()` call anywhere (like in `gui.update()`)?

Comment: `validate` is completely different from `repaint`.

Comment: I added in a `repaint` but it had no effect.

Comment: I can't see your image (firewall). How deep is the stack? Is there any possibility to get a text version?

Comment: OK, thanks. That seems to be a list of running threads rather than the stack. Still, from what I can see there, there's no obvious problem (no unusual threads). Can you right-click the EventQueue thread and suspend it, then tell me what's the user-made method that's closest to the top?

Comment: It is HumanPlayer.act at the line that reads `performedAction.wait()` (in the code above)

Comment: Ah, there's your problem then. You're calling `wait()` in a loop, but there's no other thread that can update whatever `hasPerformedAction()` is checking. You'll have to rethink that bit of the design.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will have to sit and think very hard now

Comment: Sorry one more question. does that mean that the gui will only repaint after this method returns? because I need it to repaint with a set of choices for the user and then wait for the user to perform an action and return that action

Comment: Yes, the GUI repaints on the EventQueue, so if you're doing work on it (like you are there), then it can't repaint until you're done. You might have to go to a modal design (the GUI does different things based on what mode it's in).

Comment: Can I not offload the waiting to another thread (using SwingWorker) so that the event queue becomes free and can repaint?

Comment: Yes... but you can't get input from your GUI while you're using the EventQueue, and you can't (or at least shouldn't) access your GUI from a different thread. Be very careful here.

Comment: ahh that poses a problem because I need input from the user via the GUI, hmm... this has turned out to be more work than I bargained for

Comment: As I said, a modal design might be your best bet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was instead of making the call

```
new GameInitializer(userName, player, Constants.BLIND_STRUCTURE_FILES.get(blindStructure), handState);
```

from the EDT, make it execute on a new (non EDT) thread so that later when `invokeAndWait` is called it functions as correctly as the thread running that command is not the EDT. The amended code is as follows:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       new GameInitializer(userName, player, Constants.BLIND_STRUCTURE_FILES.get(blindStructure), handState);       
    }

   });
t.start();
```

Answer (score 6):

`invokeAndWait()` is meant to be called from the non-GUI thread. It sends a `Runnable` object to the GUI thread where it will be executed.

There's no point in sending a `Runnable` object from the GUI-thread to itself. It has the same effect as calling `run()` on the `Runnable` object directly.

Comment: Yes is there another way to execute that command and wait for completion before the rest of the method is executed?

Comment: I think that's already how it works - the event thread is a single thread so it will complete the gui.update call before moving on.

Comment: What I had not understood was that THREAD does not mean METHOD/CLASS, at all. This whole issue depends on where the chain of method calls was **started**.

Answer (score 4):

You can check before if your current calling thread is already the event dispatcher:

```
private void syncExec(final Runnable r) {
    try {
        if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) r.run();
        else EventQueue.invokeAndWait(r);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        Throws.throwRuntime(e);
    }
}
```

Note that `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable)` simply delegates to the `EventQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, it appears you are not repainting the frame once the actions are completed. If you do not, then the screen will only be updated at what seems to be random times (when another window moves in front, perhaps).

Inside `gui.update`, I suggest you make the last line:

```
myFrame.repaint();
```

(more or less, depending on your circumstances).

---

**Edit:** As it turns out, the actual problem is this loop:

```
synchronized(performedAction){
    while(!hasPerformedAction()){
        try {
            performedAction.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    setPerformedAction(false);
}
```

Since there is only one application thread (which happens to be the EDT), the result of `hasPerformedAction()` can never change (assuming it's a simple getter). There is no other thread to change the value. Since this infinite loop is on the EDT, the GUI can never be repainted; hence it locks up.

Comment: I have tried this with no luck, the gui doesn't even initially paint; the screen stays white and the X in the top right hand corner doesn't kill the process

Comment: @Aly: Have you ever gotten anything to paint on the screen in this project (and then changed things later)?

Comment: yes I previously was creating a new GameInitializer from another thread (not EDT) and the gui was functioning fine. But now I have tried to make another JFrame which creates the GameInitializer which now breaks things as previously calling `invokeAndWait` was fine (as the initial thread was not EDT)

Comment: @Aly: Can you run it in a debugger and break it while the screen is white? The stacks of each thread might prove interesting.

Answer (score 0):

When using XChart java library you can show your chart on button click with this code:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("View chart");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new SwingWrapper(yourChart).displayChart();
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to execute your code from this

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {

                     }
                   });
```